# Defining Devel generation rules for custom nodes

Tags: nodes, debugging

I have Devel module installed, I use it mostly for generating content.

I wanted to know if it was possible to define some custom rules to generate content for my custom nodes.

For example: I want the node titles to be fetched from a php array or another source instead of the automatic Lorem Ipsum fragments.

I've done some google researches but I can't find a starting point to do this.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible. To get a proper answer though, please see the [FAQ] and edit the question into something a bit more meaty and useful for future visitors. Adding what you've already tried (including code examples and error messages/etc) would be the simplest way to do that

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Clive, the problem is I don't have any code yet as I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually create a simple custom module for migratig data from an external data source and no need to use devel for this kind of tasks.

you have a very good example here :

http://timonweb.com/how-programmatically-create-nodes-comments-and-taxonomies-drupal-7

you can simply adapt the code and make a foreach loop on your array.

Comment: I think I'll do it this way, it's a more time saving solution.
Thanks a lot @Sicca